# Mapping CSS elements to D3

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I have a function where I draw bar chart with D3. I need to add this CSS elements to my structure:

```
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}
```

I couldn't understand to which variables or how I should map these css elements.

I have used [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304) for my code. Basically I'm trying to map these css elements for instance like this:

```
svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)
        .append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .style("font-family","sans-serif")
        .style("font-size","10px")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("Publications");
```

But I don't know how to map `.axis path`, `.axis line` and `.x.axis path` css elements. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: You can simply include the CSS, no need to set it through D3.

Comment: How can I include it? I have tried couple of methods for including but it didn't work.

Comment: In the same way you would include it in any other HTML page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .axis path,
      .axis line {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #000;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
      }

      .x.axis path {
        display: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      svg = ...// Your code here
      yAxis = ...// Your code here
      svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)
        .append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .style("font-family","sans-serif")
        .style("font-size","10px")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("Publications");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When you execute `.call(yAxis)`, d3 creates axis-related `<path>` and `<line>` nodes inside your `<g class="y axis">`. Once d3 creates them, those node will satisfy the css selectors in `<style>` (eg `.axis path`) and turn off stroke etc. Which I believe answers what I think you're asking.